# Password problem while creating domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, installation, domain, password

I'm freshman so far in server management stuff but this seems to be clearly against logic. After updating my Windows Server 2008 Standard 32bit, installing DNS server and AD DS I wanted to create domain via using CMD and dcpromo.exe setup. But no matter if I disable demand for comlex password in Password policies or create a password which fully comply with requirements for strong and complex password, still I can't get any further and it says that my password doesn't meet requirements. I'm also asked there to activate password demand by NET USER -passwordreq:yes and when I do so, this password doesn't work any more and I have to remove it from other admin account to be at least able to login with proper Administrator account.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there is some strangeness in this particular version which requires you to run this command before you install the AD role and start dcpromo:

```
net user Administrator <password>/passwordreq:yes
```

This requirement is documented in a somewhat weasel-worded way here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755059(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the complexity of your local admin password?  Try setting it to something more complex.

Comment: I've tried passwords like: T6!h4.I4,e6?F4 and still no luck at all. I think it meets all the requirements for complex password. Don't know if there are some other settings or installations before I'm allowed to promote AD DS to domain.

Comment: Hmm. Have you created a Forest root domain yet?  I'd follow these steps if you are starting from scratch.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725897%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: I've already found the answer. It was nothing but the Windows Server 2008 bug. You will find solution here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserversetup/thread/d63052d2-8baa-447c-8012-9506f0e3124a/#a28ecf9e-082e-41fe-94a1-bbb94cf5face

Comment: You might want to post this response as an answer so that it can help other people who come along, but don't read the comments.